# Databinding only works on Android 10 if it is forced to refresh because the user activated/deactivated dark mode

Tags: android

I am trying to allow my user to take a photo and then I'm trying to show him a thumbnail of that photo as proof that it worked.

This all works fine on our test device running Android 9. On our Testdevice that runs Android 10 however, the ImageView never changes it's visibility **except** if the user changes from day theme to night theme (or vice versa) while my Fragment is in the background because the user is taking the photo. It doesn't work with changing between landscape and portrait mode either.

I suppose this is because if the day/night mode changed, the Fragment is forced to refresh. What I want to do is: Refresh in the exact same way even if the day/night mode didn't change.

my fragments XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="myPackage.modules.myModule.ModuleHandler" />

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="myPackage.modules.myModule.ModuleViewModel" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".modules.myModule.ModuleFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/module_photo_title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/module_photo_title_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/module_photo_title_margin_top"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/module_text_views_margin_start"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/module_text_views_margin_end"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/module_photo_image_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@{vm.photo}"
            android:contentDescription="@{vm.photoContentDescription}"
            android:visibility="@{vm.photoVisibility}"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/module_photo_margin_top"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/module_image_views_margin_start"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/module_image_views_margin_end"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/module_photo_title_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:src="@drawable/somthing"
            tools:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="@style/button"
            android:id="@+id/module_take_photo_button"
            android:text="@{vm.takePhotoButtonText}"
            android:onClick="@{() -> handler.executeTakePhoto()}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/module_photo_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:text="@string/module_take_photo_button_default_text" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

My Fragment class:

```
package myPackage.modules.myModule

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import myPackage.MainViewModel
import myPackage.R
import myPackage.databinding.FragmentModuleBinding

class ModuleFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        private const val permissionsRequestCode = 3
        private const val photoIntentRequestCode = 4
    }

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentModuleBinding
    private val vm: ModuleViewModel by viewModels()
    private val sharedVm: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //create binding
        binding = FragmentModuleBinding.inflate(
            inflater,
            container,
            false
        )

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        //set variables in binding
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        binding.handler = ModuleHandler(this, vm, sharedVm)
        binding.vm = vm
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        if (vm.getPhoto().value == null) {
            //set Default value
            vm.removePhoto()
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when (requestCode) {
            permissionsRequestCode -> {
                val cameraIndex = permissions.indexOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                if (
                    grantResults.getOrNull(cameraIndex) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    startCamera()
                }
            }
            else -> super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode) {
            photoIntentRequestCode -> {
                when (resultCode) {
                    Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                        val image = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
                        vm.updatePhoto(
                            BitmapDrawable(resources, image),
                            getString(R.string.module_photo_default_content_description) //TODO change text
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            else -> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }

    fun attemptStartingCamera() {
        val cameraPermissionGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        if (!cameraPermissionGranted) {
            requestPermissions(
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                ),
                permissionsRequestCode
            )
        } else {
            startCamera()
        }
    }

    //src: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics
    private fun startCamera() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).let {
            if (it.resolveActivity(requireContext().packageManager) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(it, photoIntentRequestCode)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My Handler class:

```
package myPackage.modules.myModule

import myPackage.MainViewModel

class ModuleHandler(
    private val fragment: ModuleFragment,
    private val vm: ModuleViewModel,
    private val sharedVm: MainViewModel
) {

    fun executeTakePhoto() {
        fragment.attemptStartingCamera()
    }

}
```

My ViewModel class:

```
package myPackage.modules.myModule

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.view.View
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import myPackage.R

class ModuleViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val photo = MutableLiveData<Drawable>()
    private val photoContentDescription = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val photoVisibility = MutableLiveData<Int>(View.GONE)
    private val takePhotoButtonText = MutableLiveData<Int>(R.string.module_take_photo_button_default_text)

    fun getPhoto(): LiveData<Drawable> = photo

    fun getPhotoContentDescription(): LiveData<String> = photoContentDescription

    fun getPhotoVisibility(): LiveData<Int> = photoVisibility

    fun getTakePhotoButtonText(): LiveData<Int> = takePhotoButtonText

    fun updatePhoto(photo: Drawable, contentDescription: String) {
        //this is to make sure that the content description and photo are ALWAYS set together
        this.photo.postValue(photo)
        this.photoContentDescription.postValue(contentDescription)
        this.photoVisibility.postValue(View.VISIBLE)
        this.takePhotoButtonText.postValue(R.string.module_take_photo_button_alternative_text)
    }

    fun removePhoto() {
        //this is to make sure that the content description and photo are ALWAYS set together
        this.photo.postValue(null)
        this.photoContentDescription.postValue(null)
        this.photoVisibility.postValue(View.GONE)
        this.takePhotoButtonText.postValue(R.string.module_take_photo_button_default_text)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work because of what I do in the onStart function and my usage of postValue to set the value of the LiveData objects.

In onStart I reset the photo variable (and some others) if the photo LiveData object currently doesn't have any value in it. MutableLiveData.postValue executes asynchronously and doesn't set the value immediately. When onStart gets called (because it gets started again when the app returns from the camera Intent) the value has not been set yet and it therefore removes it again.

There are two things I could do to solve this:

1. move the check to set the default values from onStart to onActivityCreated because that doesn't get called when returning from the camera Intent.
2. replace the usage of postValue with setValue.